# How to show $P(|X-E(X)|\leq x)=1\implies V(X)\leq x^2$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with finite variance. I am trying to show if $P(|X-E(X)|\leq x)=1$ then $V(X)\leq x^2$. Could somebody please help me correct my working?

$|X-E(X)|\leq x\iff(X-E(X))^2\leq x^2\iff E[(X-E(X))^2]\leq E[x^2]$
$\iff V(X)\leq E[x^2]$ by monotonicity of expectation.

So $P(|X-E(X)|\leq x)=P((X-E(X))^2\leq x^2)=P(E[(X-E(X))^2]\leq E[x^2])=P(V(X)\leq E[x^2])=1$

Then I am stuck. How can we get rid of the probability and arrive at $V(X)\leq x^2$?

Thanks.

Comment: Both $V(X)$ and $x^2$ can be taken to be real constants here  so $P(V(X)\leq E[x^2])=1$ is the same as $P(V(X)\leq x^2)=1$ which is the same as $V(X)\leq x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=X-\mathrm{E}[X]$. Then
$$
V(X)=\mathrm{E}[Y^2]=\mathrm{E}[Y^2\mathbf{1}_{|Y|\leqslant x}]\leqslant \mathrm{E}[x^2\mathbf{1}_{|Y|\leqslant x}]=x^2P(|Y|\leqslant x)=x^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how do you take out the $x^2$ in $\mathrm{E}[x^2\mathbf{1}_{|Y|\leqslant x}]=x^2P(|Y|\leqslant x)$?

Comment: @user338393 $x$ is simply a number, correct? Not a random variable? If so recall that $\operatorname{E}$ is linear.

Comment: Yeah, $x$ is a constant so you may pull it out of the expectation.